# Slick Slider with bootstrap 5 tabs pills

Tags: html, css, slider, slick.js

I'm trying to create three price cards with changing tabs and a slider of these cards when screen is smaller. I'm trying to use slick slider for this purpose. But when I use the slider and switch tabs the width of cards changes due to slider.

[When tabs are refreshed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzWvK.png)

[Switching the tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK3a6.png)

## This is the code!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- Slick Slider CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"
    />
    <!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link active"
          id="pills-home-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="pill"
          data-bs-target="#pills-home"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="pills-home"
          aria-selected="true"
        >
          Home
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link"
          id="pills-profile-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="pill"
          data-bs-target="#pills-profile"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="pills-profile"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          Profile
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link"
          id="pills-contact-tab"
          data-bs-toggle="pill"
          data-bs-target="#pills-contact"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="pills-contact"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          Contact
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- tab content -->
    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade show active"
        id="pills-home"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
        <div class="row slider">
          <!-- card 1 -->
          <div class="col-4 card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Home</h5>
              <p class="card-text">A quick brown fox jumps over thw lazy dog</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- card 2 -->
          <div class="col-4 card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Home</h5>
              <p class="card-text">A quick brown fox jumps over thw lazy dog</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- card 3 -->
          <div class="col-4 card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Home</h5>
              <p class="card-text">A quick brown fox jumps over thw lazy dog</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="pills-profile"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
        <div class="row slider">
          <!-- card 1 -->
          <div class="col-4 card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Home</h5>
              <p class="card-text">A quick brown fox jumps over thw lazy dog</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- card 2 -->
          <div class="col-4 card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Home</h5>
              <p class="card-text">A quick brown fox jumps over thw lazy dog</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- card 3 -->
          <div class="col-4 card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Home</h5>
              <p class="card-text">A quick brown fox jumps over thw lazy dog</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="pills-contact"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab"
        tabindex="0"
      >
        <div class="row slider">
          <!-- card 1 -->
          <div class="col-4 card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Home</h5>
              <p class="card-text">A quick brown fox jumps over thw lazy dog</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- card 2 -->
          <div class="col-4 card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Home</h5>
              <p class="card-text">A quick brown fox jumps over thw lazy dog</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- card 3 -->
          <div class="col-4 card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Home</h5>
              <p class="card-text">A quick brown fox jumps over thw lazy dog</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- Slick Slider JS -->
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      // Tabs
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".slider").slick({
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          autoplay: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 1500,
          arrows: false,
          dots: false,
          pauseOnHover: false,
          responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 1400,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
              },
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 1240,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
              },
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 992,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
              },
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
              },
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 576,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
        });

        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
          $(e.target)
            .parent()
            .find('a[data-toggle="tab"]')
            .each(function () {
              if ($(this).attr("aria-selected") === "true") {
                var href = $(this).attr("href");
                $(href).find(".slider").slick("refresh");
              }
            });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```